# How to move and rename a file in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a file `.pio/build/env/firmware.bin` and I want to move in another location (buildFirmwares folder). The process is always on the same main directory.

```
await File('.pio/build/env/firmware.bin').rename('/buildFirmwares/firmwares.firmware.bin');
```

`OS Error: The file can't be found.`

What I am doing wrong ? I tried `./.pio/...`, relative and absolute path but nothing works.

Comment: Does the `/buildFirmwares/` folder exist? It might need to for this to work. Otherwise, try `print(File('.pio/build/env/firmware.bin').absolute.path);` to make sure the path is relative to the folder you'd expect (this will depend on the working directory where `dart` is being executed if you haven't otherwise changed `Directory.current`).